# Segmentation error in r (invalid permissions)

Tags: c++, r, lpsolve

I'm using a recently developed tool for multiple testing problem called IHW here https://github.com/nignatiadis/IHW . It uses lpsolver SYMPHONY in C++.

When I ran the tool, there is sometimes segmentation error and sometimes it went through smoothly. The error is as below:

```
*** caught segfault ***

address 0x2adb3bfe0000, cause 'invalid permissions'
Traceback:
1: .C("lp_symphony_solve", as.integer(nc), as.integer(nr), as.integer(mat$matbeg),     as.integer(mat$matind), as.double(mat$values), as.double(col_lb),     as.double(col_ub), as.integer(int), if (max) as.double(-obj) else as.double(obj),     obj2 = double(nc), as.character(paste(row_sense, collapse = "")),     as.double(rhs), double(), objval = double(1L), solution = double(nc),     status = integer(1L), verbosity = as.integer(verbosity),     time_limit = as.integer(time_limit), node_limit = as.integer(node_limit),     gap_limit = as.double(gap_limit), first_feasible = as.integer(first_feasible),     write_lp = as.integer(write_lp), write_mps = as.integer(write_mps))
2: lpsymphony::lpsymphony_solve_LP(obj, constr_matrix, rep("<=",     nrow(constr_matrix)), rhs, max = TRUE, verbosity = -2, first_feasible = FALSE)
3: ihw_convex(filtered_split_sorted_pvalues, alpha, m_groups_holdout_fold,     penalty = penalty, lambda = lambda, lp_solver = lp_solver,     quiet = quiet, ...)
4: ihw_internal(filtered_sorted_groups, filtered_sorted_pvalues,     alpha, lambda, seed = NULL, quiet = quiet, nfolds = nfolds_internal,     distrib_estimator = distrib_estimator,lp_solver = lp_solver)
5: ihw_internal(sorted_groups, sorted_pvalues, alpha, lambdas, penalty = penalty,     quiet = quiet, nfolds = nfolds, nfolds_internal = nfolds_internal,     nsplits_internal = nsplits_internal, seed = NULL, distrib_estimator = distrib_estimator,     lp_solver = lp_solver, ...)
6: ihw(qtls$pvalue, qtls$hic, alpha = alpha) aborting ... /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1757656.scheduler.SC: line 16: 27802 Segmentation fault
```

My info session is shown below:

```
sessionInfo ()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: You should report this as a bug to the maintainer of the `lpsymphony` package.

Comment: @Y.He Have you managed to fix this problem?